# Using Spring EL to add optional postfix from properties to consumerGroup in @KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-el

I have simple spring boot application with Kafka Consumers that looks like

```
@KafkaListener(topics="topic", groupId="SOME_CONSTANT") {
....
}
```

What I am required to do Is to add optional spring boot property (from env variables but that is not important) lets say:
`myapp.env: TEST`

And when that variable is present I should automatically update consumer group to be
`SOME_CONSTANT-TEST`

I am playing with SPEL

```
@KafkaListener(topics="topic", groupId="#{ '${myApp.env}' == null ? 'SOME_CONSTANT' : 'SOME_CONSTANT' + '-' + '${myApp.env}}'") {
....
}
```

But that does not seem to work :/ Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `T` operator to read the constant's value, and use the colon ':' for the case when there's no env variable:

`@KafkaListener(topics="topic", groupId="#{ '${my.app.env:}' == '' ? T(com.mypackage.MyListener).SOME_CONSTANT : T(com.mypackage.MyListener).SOME_CONSTANT + '-' + '${my.app.env:}'}")`

Here's a sample application with this solution:

```
package org.spring.kafka.playground;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaOperations;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SO71291726 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SO71291726.class, args);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.interrupted();
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted");
        }
        KafkaOperations kafkaTemplate = context.getBean("kafkaTemplate", KafkaOperations.class);
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "My message");
    }

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "my-group-id-constant";

    @Component
    class MyListener {

        @KafkaListener(topics="topic", groupId="#{ '${71291726.my.app.env:}' == '' ? T(org.spring.kafka.playground.SO71291726).SOME_CONSTANT : T(org.spring.kafka.playground.SO71291726).SOME_CONSTANT + '-' + '${71291726.my.app.env:}'}")
        void listen(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) String groupId) {
            log.info("Received message {} from group id {} ", message, groupId);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
`2022-02-28 14:26:14.733  INFO 18841 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] 1291726$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf264156 : Received message My message from group id my-group-id-constant`

If I add `71291726.my.app.env = TEST` to the `application.properties` file:

`2022-02-28 14:34:03.900  INFO 18870 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] 1291726$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1a5933e : Received message My message from group id my-group-id-constant-TEST`